# Type or namespace could not be found AFTER Package is restored

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package-restore

We are really struggling with this error with our nuget packages when we are using TFS.  A team member will add a package and it will inevitably not be found when we pull it.  In the past, we've manually added the packages but we stumbled upon Package Restore!  This is an awesome tool but it doesn't seem to work always as I would expect.

These are the steps I have been taking when a simple "Enable Package Restore" and rebuilding doesn't fix it.

1. Delete the Nuget and Packages folder from the solution.
2. Restart Visual Studio
3. Clean solution
4. Rebuild solution

Now, this gets me there with probably 90% of the packages but there are still some that won't resolve.  The weird part is, I've looked in the packages folder and I SEE the missing package installed after I build/rebuild even though it still shows that it is missing.

So, barring a better method to get these to automatically be restored, is there a way I can force it to look at the package location?

Comment: any specific version requirements requested?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @DanielA.White VS 2013, I've added that tag at the bottom. Thanks John Saunders

Comment: i mean does the package name a specific version?

Comment: @DanielA.White Where do I see the named version?  Do I have to go manually look it up in the nuget?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this too, but so long ago I don't remember how it was solved.

I would carefully check that the specific version listed in the project matches exactly the version that was pulled down into packages. That no hint path or other magic was applied to the assemblies, that they are overridden in some way in the web/application config to look somewhere else or a different, now missing value.

Comment: Where do I check the version incompatibilities?

Comment: The package contains assemblies, and these you can view in references and see the version. Then in the package folder itself, dive into the lib folder to find the matching assembly there. You can then right click, view properties and see the version. They should match

Comment: Within references they all show as missing (yellow, triangle exclamation point).  This happens with multiple projects.

Comment: So the trick is to find the package that is supposed have the missing assembly, then compare the versions of those assemblies if they are present. A simple windows explorer search in the packages folder should accomplish the first step. My earlier comment explains how to compare versions.